# Comparing two sets of data with Intersection in Python

Tags: python, set, set-intersection

When comparing two sets, following_id and follower_id, the return result seems to be splitting everything.

```
import re
id1 = '[User(ID=1234567890, ScreenName=RandomNameHere), User(ID=233323490,      ScreenName=AnotherRandomName), User(ID=4459284, ScreenName=YetAnotherName)]'
id2 = '[User(ID=1234467890, ScreenName=sdf), User(ID=233323490,  ScreenName=AnotherRandomName), User(ID=342, ScreenName=443)]'

following_id = ', '.join( re.findall(r'ID=(\d+)', id1) )
follower_id = ', '.join( re.findall(r'ID=(\d+)', id2) )

a = list(set(following_id).intersection(follower_id))
print a
```

This results with `[' ', ',', '1', '0', '3', '2', '5', '4', '7', '6', '9', '8']`

I would like the results to be `['233323490','54321']` which are the two IDs that match between the two sets.

The following works for me:

```
list1 = [1234567890, 233323490, 4459284, 230, 200, 234, 200, 0002]
list2 = [1234467890, 233323490, 342, 101, 234]
a = list(set(list1).intersection(list2))
print a
```

With a result of `[233323490, 234]`

Does this have to do with the datatype for following_id and follower_id?

Comment: `'.'.join()` will return a single string. Maybe if you remove that in the definition of `following_id` and `follower_id`, after all, you need these two to be list to find intersection? `re.findall()` already return a list

Comment: @Tuan333 Makes sense, thank you for the quick reply.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because you're making `strings` with `.join`, not `lists`:

```
following_id = ', '.join( re.findall(r'ID=(\d+)', id1) )
follower_id = ', '.join( re.findall(r'ID=(\d+)', id2) )
print(following_id) # '1234567890, 233323490, 4459284'
print(follower_id) # '1234467890, 233323490, 342'
```

You just need to use:

```
following_id = re.findall(r'ID=(\d+)', id1)
follower_id = re.findall(r'ID=(\d+)', id2)
```

As `re.findall` already returns a `list` of matches.

Comment: Quick response!  That makes sense.  Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

`following_id` and `follower_id` are strings. When you convert a string to a set, you'll get a set of each of the characters:

```
>>> set('hello, there')
{' ', 'o', 't', 'e', 'r', 'h', ',', 'l'}
```

When making the set, Python doesn't care about the commas or spaces in your string... it just iterates over the characters treating each as an item in the new set.

You're looking for a set of strings.  So you need to pass something that contains strings to then turn into a set.  `re.findall` should give you make a list of strings.  If you don't join them together, you should be able to take the intersection and get what you're looking for:

```
following_id = re.findall(r'ID=(\d+)', id1)
follower_id = re.findall(r'ID=(\d+)', id2)

a = list(set(following_id).intersection(follower_id))
```

Comment: Great explanation!!